# which dxl script run when a module is opened in Doors

Tags: ibm-doors

I am new to DOORs technology. It may be a very silly question but I don't find a way to get the dxl script which gets run for below scenario.

I have a module in DOORS. When a module is opened in exclusive edit mode, a dxl script runs and does some job.

How do I find out which dxl script run when a module is opened.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword you are looking for is a *trigger*. Triggers are an event-based approach to customization. DOORS executes triggers on various occasions, including opening of a module (trigger level = module, event = open/read/edit). There is a chapter dedicated to triggers in the DXL manual which will surely provide the details you need.

According to the manual, you may use the simple iterator to check all triggers of a module and see if there is such an open-module trigger for your module:

```
Module mod = current Module
print "Listing triggers for module '" name(mod) "':\n"

Trigger t
for t in mod do {
    print "  Name    : '" name(t) "'\n" 
    print "  DXL code: '" dxl(t) "'\n\n"
}
```

If you still miss your trigger, maybe it's a project / database trigger. You will find those by using the iterators `for t in current Project` and `for t in database` respectively.

Be careful with using triggers. For some insight, see Hazel Woodcock's [Tips on reducing module open times](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/35dfcb99-111b-423a-aaa4-50f3fddae141/entry/doors_tips_reducing_module_open_times?lang=en).